# PLink telnet from Excel VBA - avoid login delay, or maintain session for multiple queries

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, telnet, plink

I have a Linux box which I'm testing, and I have an Excel workbook with tables of tests I'm running. (Don't get tied up on Linux, it's just a Telnet target for the purposes of this question.) The workbook starts a telnet session with the Linux box, then issues commands to set some variables (simulating real world inputs). Then, the workbook reads back the results of the job the Linux box has run based on the input variables.

I tried http://officetricks.com/start-telnet-session-from-excel-autorun-commands/, but MSWinsockLib is not available (defunct? I'm using Win10 / M365).

So I've found some articles on sending a command line and reading the result, and using PLink, it's working:

Execute command and read result: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55158380/2317071
Skip PLink prompt acknowledgment when connecting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57736579/2317071

The problem I'm having, is that the telnet session takes 4 seconds per command, I believe largely due to the initial login / acknowledgement prompt. That doesn't sound like much, but I've got **thousands** (potentially tens of thousands!) of commands to send (and my PC is unusable while the macro is running).

So, I'd like to know:

1. Is there any way to avoid this delay using PLink?
2. Is there any way to open the telnet session, keep it open, send new commands and record the individual results?
3. Is there any better way to interrogate a telnet/ssh target from Excel? (I've spent too many hours searching, to come up with nothing!)

Here's the code I've *stolen* err *borrowed* err **learnt** from the other StackExchange / StackOverflow posts:

```
'https://stackoverflow.com/a/55158380/2317071
Function F_shellExec(sCmd As String) As String

    F_ShellExec_StartTime = Now()
    Dim oShell   As New WshShell 'requires ref to Windows Script Host Object Model
    Debug.Print "F_shellExec: sCmd = " & sCmd
    F_shellExec = oShell.Exec(sCmd).StdOut.ReadAll
    F_ShellExec_EndTime = Now()
    F_ShellExec_ExecTime = F_ShellExec_EndTime - F_ShellExec_StartTime
    Debug.Print "F_shellExec took " & Format(F_ShellExec_ExecTime, "HH:MM:SS")
End Function

Sub ShellExec_tests()

    PLink_Call = "plink.exe -batch -ssh user@10.10.10.10 -pw " & SSHPassWord & " "
    Shell_Cmd = "databaseread -t Tag.To.Read.Value.From"

    Debug.Print "Shell_Cmd = " & Shell_Cmd
    Debug.Print F_shellExec(PLink_Call & Shell_Cmd)
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `MSWinsockLib` is still around, but is 32-bit only (requiring 32-bit Excel), but plink is probably better for ssh. If you just need to run multiple commands, you can string them together with `;` like `plink.exe [options] [host] echo hello; echo world` assuming the remote system is running bash for example.

Comment: As far as other ways, it depends on why you're using excel for this at all. For any use case I can think of, it would be far simpler to run a powershell/python/vba style script, and just query from/write back to your excel from there. If you're getting data from a database, there many ways to connect excel directly

Comment: But if those aren't an option, and you basically need an interactive ssh session to go back and forth from, you can technically use SendKeys to input commands into an existing ssh.exe session started using `WshShell`, but I don't recommend it

Comment: @Cpt.Whale - Thanks for the look-in. Yes, I'm familiar with joining commands with `;` in bash. I think some of my bash alias' on my Linux system have about 25 commands called from one alias. :) I'm looping through rows, each row decides if it is needed, then it sends the write commands. I was previously sending about 3 write commands joined together in one telnet command; but I think I've just made it do all possible writes from one line at once (testing now). Then I send the read commands, but I need to parse the response from each read, so they can only be done one at a time.